# Can I "attach" more than 5 Custom Variables to the same _trackPageview with Google Analytics Premium?

Tags: google-analytics

This line can be found in the [Google Analytics Custom Variable Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables)

> **You have up to 5 simultaneous custom variables for use in a single
>   request (e.g. pageview or event call).** The sum of all your custom
>   varaiables cannot exceed 5 in any given request (i.e. you cannot have
>   5 visitor and 5 session custom variables set simultaneously).

Is this a limitation of the javascript/beacon and/or a limitation of the way GA rolls up events in the free version of Google Analytics?

To reword with code, would this work if I am on an account that pays for GA Premium?

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Foo', "Bar", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Biz', "Baz", 2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'Ugg', "Bot", 3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, 'Big', "Bug", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'Sun', "Tin", 2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 6, 'Hor', "Ton", 3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 7, 'Saw', "Who", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 8, 'Dis', "Dat", 2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 9, 'Who', "Der", 3]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "cat", "action", "lbl", 0, true]);
```

Or would I have to structure the above code like this:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Foo', "Bar", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Biz', "Baz", 2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'Ugg', "Bot", 3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, 'Big', "Bug", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'Sun', "Tin", 2]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 6, 'Hor', "Ton", 3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 7, 'Saw', "Who", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 8, 'Dis', "Dat", 2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 9, 'Who', "Der", 3]);
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "cat", "action", "lbl", 0, true]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can attach up to 50 custom variables to Google Analytics Premium. So that statement for Google Analytics Premium customers should be read:

> You have up to 50 simultaneous custom variables for use in a single
>   request (e.g. pageview or event call). The sum of all your custom
>   varaiables cannot exceed 50 in any given request (i.e. you cannot have
>   50 visitor and 50 session custom variables set simultaneously).

The correct way to do it is the first one

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Foo', "Bar", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Biz', "Baz", 2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'Ugg', "Bot", 3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, 'Big', "Bug", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'Sun', "Tin", 2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 6, 'Hor', "Ton", 3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 7, 'Saw', "Who", 1]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 8, 'Dis', "Dat", 2]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 9, 'Who', "Der", 3]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "cat", "action", "lbl", 0, true]);
```

Note that the javascript code for premium and free are the same. So if you try to do that in Google Analytics Free version it will look like it works, but the extra variables above 5 are ignored on the processing backend unless you have Google Analytics Premium Edition.

More information about Google Analytics Premium

http://www.google.com/analytics/premium/features.html